# Override trait function in the intersection of two mixins

Tags: scala, overriding, traits, mixins, implicit

The thing is, is there any way (That does not involve reflective black magic), to implicitly override a method, when two known traits are implemented?

Think that we have a class `SysImpl` that implements two mixins: `System` and `Container`:

```scala
// Where system acts as the interface for another consumer
trait System {
  def isEmpty = false
}

trait Container[A] {
  val elements = mutable.Set[A]()
}

// Then, we typically implement:
class SysImpl extends System with Container[Int] {
  // We override the default system implementation here
  override def isEmpty = elements.isEmpty
}
```

Just as an example.
Is there any way of implementing either a third trait, or making something to the original, that makes the implementation implicitly override the `isEmpty` method, in case that `System` & `Container[A]` are present?

The first thing that comes to my mind is creating an extension method, but that would be shadowing at its best (Wouldn't it?). I need the method to be overridden properly, as the call is dispatched by a consumer who only sees `System`s.

(Example, omitting details)

```scala
class AImpl extends System with Container[A]

object Consumer {
  def consume(sys: System) = if (sys.isEmpty) { /* Do things */ }
}

// Somewhere...
object Main {
  def main() = {
    Consumer.consume(new AImpl)
  }
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't `Container` implement `isEmpty`?

Comment: Well, I've used the word `isEmpty` here but is more like a `isUnused` in my implementation, also is the consumer of the `System` who needs to know if the `System` is ready to be deactivated. And the consumer does not know about `Container[A]`

Comment: Why not just introducing a third trait that extends those two, and overrides the `isEmpty` and then instead of extending those two `SysImpl` will just extend this new trait?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez That could be one solution indeed

Answer (score 2):

Just

```
  trait Mix[A] extends Container[A] with System {
    override def isEmpty = elements.isEmpty
  }
```